# JSON post encoding in Elasticsearch through maven

Tags: java, json, maven, elasticsearch

I want to make insert in java.Maven with http post to Elasticsearch server.
My code is:

```java
package com.server.java.Webping;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ReadAndWrite extends Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.126:9200/shakespeare/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @shakespeare.json");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        File file = new File("shakespeare.json");
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String input = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while(br.readLine( ) != null) 
        {
            String txt = br.readLine( );                                     
            builder.append(txt);
        }                                
        input = builder.toString();

        OutputStream os = (OutputStream) conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br1.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

However when I execute the post method, java return me an error:

```
java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:699)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:711)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1567)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at com.server.java.Webping.ReadAndWrite.main(ReadAndWrite.java:38)
```

I have also checked my server connection with pinging socket request and its working .
code for pinging request:

```java
package com.server.java.Webping;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

  public class WebPing {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          try {
             InetAddress addr;
             Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.1.126", 9200);   // elastic search - 9200 , kibana - 5601
             addr = sock.getInetAddress();
             System.out.println("Connected to " + addr);
             sock.close();
          } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
             System.out.println("Can't connect to " + args[0]);
             System.out.println(e);
          }
       }
    }
```

and output returns as :
Connected to /192.168.1.126

Can anyone help me out that what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Once you connect to `192.168.1.126:5601` (kibana) and once to `localhost:9200` (elasticsearch), what does that prove?

Comment: I am sorry actually both should be http://192.168.1.126:9200...